# Navigation.push won't render new params from route

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hi I got a list and list details page.

In the details page I got links for other details page. Since they are the same component. I am using the navigation.push to go to another details page.

`details a -> details b`

The thing is when I press the link button. I am hoping React native will re-render the details component will new `route-params`. But I does not happen. Its still show me the old details. Can someone please take a look

```
const CaseDetails = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const scrollRef = useRef();

  const {
    title,
    summary,
    gallery,
    image,
    challenge,
    solution,
    result,
  } = route.params;

  const caseList = useSelector((state) => state.articlesReducer.caseList);

  const listToRender = caseList.filter((item) => item.title !== title);

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={item.id}
        onPress={() => {
              navigation.push('CaseDetails', {
            screen: 'CaseDetails',
            params: {
              title: item.title,
              summary: item.summary,
              image: item.image,
              challenge: item.challenge,
              solution: item.solution,
              result: item.result,
              gallery: item.gallery,
            },
          });
        }}>
        <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.sliderImage}
            source={{
              uri: `${baseUri}/${item.image}`,
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };



  return (
    <ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
      <View style={globalStyle.articleLandingContainer}>
        <Image
          style={globalStyle.articleLandingImage}
          source={{
            uri: `${baseUri}/${image}`,
          }}
        />
        <View style={globalStyle.articleLandingOverlay}></View>
        <Text style={styles.landingText}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.landingPara}>{summary}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 12}}>
        <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>Challenge</Text>
        <Text style={styles.contentPara}>{challenge}</Text>
      </View>

      <Carousel data={gallery} generateFor="cases" />

      <FlatList
        style={styles.bottomMargin}
        data={listToRender}
        horizontal
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

`When I using navigation.push`
Take note that when I console.log the route.params
It will only show me the params of `DetailsA` , its never updated to `detailsB` or `detailsC`.

More notes

I am coming into details pages from listpage. The thing is that `list page` and `details pages` got different stacks.

here are the codes

```
const CasesStackScreen = createMyStackNavigator(
    'Customer Cases',
    Cases,
    'CasesStack',
);
const CaseDetailsStackScreen = createMyStackDetailsNavigator(
    'Case Details',
    CaseDetails,
    'CaseDetailsStack',
    'Case Details',
);


// My DIY Stack Creator
const createMyStackNavigator = (name, screen, whatStack) => ({navigation}) => {
    whatStack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
        <whatStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {backgroundColor: `${headerColor}`},
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
            }}>
        </whatStack.Navigator>
    );
};

// cart button && Go back previous Screen
const createMyStackDetailsNavigator = (
    name,
    screen,
    whatStack,
    destination,
) => ({navigation}) => {
    whatStack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
        <whatStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {backgroundColor: `${headerColor}`},
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
            }}>
            
        </whatStack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Comment: you are calling a nested screen of a navigator (CaseDetails in CaseDetails). If you are not doing it, you can simplify it to `navigation.push('CaseDetails', {...params})`

Comment: I done as you mention , but what happen is when I click the `button`  the `page transfer animation` happen. but the render data are the old datas.
is it related to stacks when creating?